# Rewrite url if a specific word exist

Tags: url-rewriting

Hello I am confused with the rewritecond, I want when in the url exist a specific word for example uniquenumber the domain to change so for example when someone types domain.com/br/news.php?uniquenumder=1 then to change in a newdomain.com/br/news.php?uniquenumber=1. The only change is in the domain from domain.com to newdomain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are talking about apache and mod_rewrite module.

From apache docs http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

> The RewriteCond directive defines a rule condition. One or more
>   RewriteCond can precede a RewriteRule directive. The following rule is
>   then only used if both the current state of the URI matches its
>   pattern, and if these conditions are met.

Look at the following example

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /www/domain.com
    ServerName domain.com
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond  %{QUERY_STRING} ^uniquenumber=1$    
    RewriteRule  .* http://one.domain.com/?      [L,R=301]
    RewriteCond  %{QUERY_STRING} ^uniquenumber=2$    
    RewriteRule  .* http://two.domain.com/?      [L,R=301]
    # ...
</VirtualHost>
```

The above will redirect 
domain.com/br/news.php?uniquenumder=1 to one.domain.com
and
domain.com/br/news.php?uniquenumder=2 to two.domain.com
You just have to create the rules that suit your needs.

Of course, you could just take the RewriteRule lines and place them inside a .htaccess file.

You can test your rewrite rules [HERE](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/)

Comment: Actually the uniquenumber will take many numbers from 1 to some thusands so for a example the 1 could be 1234 and it needs to be redirected to a new desination that only the main domain will change. The problem is that there is a website that is already successful and some urls of that site can be found across the web, yet we have to put in that domain a new one a wordpress so we thought that we could put a redirect to domain.com that when someone press an old url a new will be restructed and send him to the new destination newdomain, all the old urls have the uniquenumderin them.Thank you so!

Comment: Mskolari Could I use such a solution to httpacess? and not in a apache? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Yeah I've seen it, the conditionals work well, I am trying to figure out how to place the requested url after the one.domain.com for example. I tried to place %{REQUEST_URI} after the one.domain.com/ yet it amends the old to the new for example I get one.domain.com/domain.com/open-news.php?uniquenumber=1

Comment: I came to this that works except for amending the whole url requested :(                                                   <VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /www/domain.com
    ServerName domain.com
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond  %{QUERY_STRING} ^uniquenumber= *$    
    RewriteRule  .* http://one.domain.com/%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]     
        
    
    # ...
</VirtualHost>'code'